# other way of proving the limit of $\frac{10^n}{n!}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

My textbook is asking me to find the limit of $\frac{10^n}{n!}$. Here is how they do it:[image]

My question is: Is this the only way to prove that the limit is $0$ ?

I know the fact that factorials diverge 'faster' than exponential, so can I just state this? I mean how am I supposed to know that at $n>20$ the ratio is $<\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Or should I just say that for some $N$, there is $n>N$ s.t. the ratio of the successive terms become less than $1$ and hence the limit is $0$?

Comment: "Less than $1$" is not enough. You need "Less than $q$" for some $q<1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{10^{n+1}/(n+1)!}{10^n/n!} = \frac{10}{n+1}$$
From here it's quite easy to tell that for $n\geq 20$, this ratio is less than $\frac12$.

You are, in some sense, not supposed to **know** this. You are supposed to know a bunch of different general tips and tricks for evaluating limits (along with the general grasp of algebra needed to actually use them), among them trying to evaluate $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}$ when you suspect that the limit is $0$ or $\infty$. It may not be the *first* thing you try, but is should probably at latest be second or third.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see now that I just had to solve the equation of successive terms. Also, why is the ratio supposed to be lesser than 1/2? Is this some rule?

Comment: @ThePoorJew No special reason. They could've taken $n\geq 11$ and $\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}< \frac{10}{11}$ if they wanted. Any constant less than $1$ would've worked. It's just that $\frac12$ is a nice number to work with.

Comment: ok, got it. Was confused why exactly 1/2 since it enough for it to be <1. Thanks for the answer and clarifying it. I see now that this question is stupid :D

Answer (score 0):

When you have that the ratio at $n>20$ is less than $\frac{1}{2}$, you obtain that $\frac{10^n}{n!} < c \frac{1}{2^n}$ for some $c$. This now converges to $0$.

Comment: how am I supposed to know the fact that for n>20---> the ratio is this? What if this comes up on an exam?

Comment: The exact value of the ratio is just $\frac{10}{n+1}$. It should be rather trivial to solve.

Comment: @Bernard you are right. I think I rushed to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider positive series $\sum\frac{10^n}{n!}$.
Let $a_n=\frac{10^n}{n!}$, and 
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{10}{n+1}=0.$$
So the positive series $\sum\frac{10^n}{n!}$ is convergent, and  $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{10^n}{n!}=0.$$

Comment: thanks, nice way of doing it

Answer (score 0):

Option:

$e^x=1+x +x^2/2! +...x^k/k!+...$, converges for $x \in.\mathbb{R}.$

Hence $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x^n/n!=0.$

Set $x=10$, i.e consider $e^{10}$.

Comment: I'd say that the convergence of $e^x$ is a consequence of this limit being $0$, so you cannot use it in the proof. Unless you have another way to show that this series is convergent?

Comment: Adam.Used the theorem that the expansion e^x converges for real x. It can be proven applying the ratio test.

Comment: Using the ratio test is basically the same method that OP was questioning, but fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be specific about what it means that factorial grows faster than exponential. And if you think about it, it means that $$ \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{a^n}{n!} = 0$$
This is basically what you need to prove, so you cannot use that in the proof. Comparing this sequence with a geometric series is the easiest way I know.

As for you last question, you need a bit stronger condition. If you have $x_n>0$ and can prove that there exist $q<1$ and $N$ such that for $n>N$ you have
$$ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} < q$$
then it is enough to prove that $x_n\rightarrow 0$. This is because you have then
$$\forall n>N: x_{n} < x_{N} \cdot q^{n-N} \rightarrow 0$$
which means $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n =0$$

Knowing just that $$ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} < 1$$ is not enough, for example for $x_n = \frac{n}{2n-1}$ you have
$$ \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n} = \frac{(n+1)(2n-1)}{(2n+1)n} = \frac{2n^2+n-1}{2n^2+n} < 1$$ but $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} x_n = \frac12$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach which you may find useful.

After a certain value of $n$ the ratio of successive terms is less than $1$ and hence the sequence is decreasing after a certain point. Also every term of the sequence is positive and hence the sequence tends to a limit (remember, monotone and bounded sequences are convergent), say $L$, and we have $L\geq 0$. Since $$x_{n+1}=\frac{10}{n+1}\cdot x_n$$ it follows by taking limits that $L=0\cdot L$ so that $L=0$.